# type of literal words

Tags: rebol, red

I was reading [Bindology](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Bindology) and tried this:

```
>> type? first ['x]
== lit-word!
>> type? 'x
== word!
```

I expected `type? 'x` to return `lit-word!` too. Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LIT-WORD! if seen in a "live" context by the evaluator resolves to the word itself.  It can be used to suppress evaluation simply with a single token when you want to pass a WORD! value to a function.  *(Of course, in  your own dialects when you are playing the role of "evaluator", it's a Tinker-Toy and you can make it mean whatever you want.)*

Had you wanted to get an actual LIT-WORD! you would have to somehow suppress the evaluator from turning it into a WORD!.  You noticed that can be achieved by picking it out of an unevaluated block, such as with `first ['x]`.  But the more "correct" way is to use `quote 'x`:

```
>> type? quote 'x
== lit-word!
```

Beware an odd bug known as "lit-word decay":

```
>> x-lit: quote 'x
>> type? x-lit
== word!
```

That has been [corrected in Red](https://github.com/red/red/issues/734) and is pending correction in Rebol.  Until then you have to use a GET-WORD! to extract a lit-word value from the variable holding it:

```
>> x-lit: quote 'x
>> type? :x-lit
== lit-word!
```

*(You may have already encountered this practice as the way of fetching the value of a word vs. "running" it through the evaluator...as when you want to deal with a function's value vs. invoking it.  It should not be necessary on values holding lit-word!.  Accident of history, it would seem.)*